# When I call request permissions to PHPhotoLibrary in the UIActivityViewController it calls twice

Tags: swift, phphotolibrary

I created `UIActivityViewController` and check which share type is select. I need to save in my photo library and I check `.saveToCameraRoll`. If I don't call `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization` in the `activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler` then it always returns status like `.notDetermined` and shows permission request once. When I call `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization` in the caomplitionHandler it shows permission alert twice and when I allow access in the second alert I can check status as expected.
My code:

````
        let sourceRect = rect ?? CGRect(x: frame.minX, y: frame.maxY - 1, width: frame.width, height: 1)

        activityVC.modalPresentationStyle = .popover
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceRect = sourceRect
        activityVC.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = viewController?.view

        activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
            guard activity == .saveToCameraRoll else { return }
            PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ _ in
                if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized {
                    //here I show alert 
                }
            })
        }

        viewController?.present(activityVC, animated: true, completion: nil)```
````

Comment: Why do you do `if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized `, and not use  the param that you silenced `_` in the completion block?

Comment: if the user denied access to the library I'll show the alert that the app needs it to save screenshots

Comment: I mean shouldn't it be `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ status in if status != .authorized { //here I show alert } })` instead of ``PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({ _ in if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized { //here I show alert } })``

Comment: Good point. But it still will ask permission twice

Comment: At the first time I tryed like this 
```activityVC.completionWithItemsHandler = { activity, success, items, error in
            guard activity == .saveToCameraRoll else { return }
            if PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus() != .authorized {
                    //here I show alert 
            }
        }```
but it doesn't show the correct status if I denied access and trying to save again

Comment: How many time is this code called in that closure? Could it be called twice, and since the authorization is async, you have a mismatch?

Comment: yes it calls async
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phphotolibrary/1620736-requestauthorization

but without `PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization` it calls too